# how to color specific strings in standard output and standard error

Tags: shell, pipe, colors, output

How do you color specific strings in standard output and standard error?

For example:

```
gpg --verify
```

Outputs either a `good signature` or a `bad signature` string.

How can I color the good one, green; and the bad one, red, using GNU software only?

In: [this document](http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gcrypt-devel/2011-May/001781.html), the developer talks about a wrapper script.

I want to do this without adding code to the source code of `gpg` to colorize those strings.

Comment: Similar question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46562/how-do-you-colorize-only-some-keywords-for-a-bash-script

Answer (score 1):

You may be after: `\e[32m` style escape sequences in your string such as

```
echo -e "Doing ls\n\e[32m$(ls --color=never)\e[33m ^^^\n \e[36m ls \e[39m output"
printf "\e[35mHello\e[41mWorld\e[0m!"
```

There are a few articles & listings of colours including:
http://www.bashguru.com/2010/01/shell-colors-colorizing-shell-scripts.html?m=1