# View text file and highlight numbers

Tags: bash, text, gedit

I'd like to view a text file on the terminal and highlight its numbers. Something like I get when I open it with `gedit`.
I haven't been able to do this with `less`, `cat`, `vim` or other viewers/editors.

P.S. My question is straightforward, but I haven't been able to find the correct keywords for a meaningful search.

## DIY solution

### Solution A

Match every number and highlights it, print every line:

```
egrep --colour=always '[-+]?[0-9]*[\.e]?[0-9]|$'
```

I guess I'll simply alias this.
I'm still wondering if there's a default option.

Edit: adding support for exponential `e`, tnx to @αғsнιη.

### Solution B

Alright, my final solution below

```
grep -P --colour=always '(?:^|(?<=[\\, ;\-\+\*\/]))[-+]?[0-9]*[\.eE]?[0-9]+|$'
```

It looks behind for separation characters or beginning of line, and matches a great deal of number formats and the end of the line (so that every line is printed).

Finally, two useful aliases `v`iew and `l`ess-`v`iew:

```
alias v="grep --colour=always -P '(?:^|(?<=[\\, ;\-\+\*\/]))[-+]?[0-9]*[\.eE]?[0-9]+|$'"
function lv {                                                                    
    v $1 | less -R                                                               
}
```

### Solution C

Here a better regex expression (to use within the single quotes of **Solution B**):

```
(?<![\w\.])[-+]?[0-9]*[\.eE]?\-?[0-9]+|$
```

This solution accounts for any non alphanumeric and dot separation symbols.
The previous one was lacking of generality.

Edit: adding `-nT` to `grep` shows aligned line numbers.
Edit2: account for negative exponents by adding `\-?`.

### TL;DR

Paste this in your `~/.bashrc` and use the `v`, `lv`, `cv` to *view*, *less-view*, and *column-view* your text files:

```
# Highlight numbers when displaying text files
alias v="grep --colour=always -nTP '(?<![\w\.])[-+]?\-?[0-9]*[\.eE]?[0-9]+|$'"
# Send v output to less
function lv {
    v $1 | less -R
}
# Convert CSV to TSV and send to lv
function cv {
    column -ts, $1 | lv
}
```

Edit: add CSV file reading shortcut and comments.

Answer (score 8):

Match also +/- signs and `e` as well.

```
 grep -E --color '[-+\.]?[0-9](|[eE][-+]?[0-9]|$)'
```

This will match below various of numbers.

```
12345
-12345
+12345
.12345
12.345
12345.
123e45
123E45
123E+45
123E-45
123e+45
123e-45
```

Comment: or `grep --color '[[:digit:]]'`

Comment: Yeah, more or less what I've suggested above. So, isn't there any default command, is it?

Comment: You need to add `|$` to print every line, though.

Comment: Also you need to escape the `\.`, otherwise you'll match everything.

Comment: Also, I don't think you need the `+` at all.

Answer (score 4):

With `vim`:

```
:syn on
:syn match Number '\v[-+]?\d*\.?\d+([eE][-+]?\d+)?'
```

That's if you only want numbers (at least this format of numbers, you could also want to add 0x123, 1,23, 0x1ap-2, VII, 1,000,000, ...) highlighted. Many syntax highlighters shipped with `vim` for different languages will also highlight numbers as understood by the corresponding language.

If you do a:

```
grep -F '[eE' /usr/share/vim/vim*/syntax/*
```

you'll see all the languages that have some forms of numbers including ones with scientific notation highlighted by `vim`.

You may also want to decide in which context those numbers may be highlighted, like should the 1 be highlighted in `ls.1`, `PS1`, `1+2`, `-1-`? Should `1e2` or `2e3` or none be highlighted in `1e2e3`, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Some other possibilities:

```
Colorize, color text

        0) reset-no-color (local), Emits sequence to remove (stray) color
           echo -e "\[\033[0;00m\]"

        1) coforma (local), color for match, add specified color for pattern
           matches

        2) coteli (local), insert ANSI color codes around line blocks,
           COlor TExt LInes

        3) spc, "supercat", colorize and print to standard output,
           general (but therefore complex) rules for coloring.
           Found in Debian repository and at:
           https://github.com/tanderson92/supercat

        4) ansifilter, convert color codes, etc., to HTML, BBcode, others
           http://www.andre-simon.de/

        5) my-highlight (local)
           http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46562/how-do-you-colorize-only-some-keywords-for-a-bash-script

        6) my-hilite (local)
           http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46562/how-do-you-colorize-only-some-keywords-for-a-bash-script

        7) hh, easy highlighting, wrapper around ack
           https://github.com/paoloantinori/hhighlighter

        8) pygmentize, parse and colorize program source file
           In Debian package python-pygments
```

For example, I ran:

```
spc data1
```

with a configuration file of .spcrc:

```
Cyan                 cya     t ([0-9]+)
```

to get:

```
Mike Brady 2
Carol 3.1415 Brady
77 Greg Brady
Marcia Brady
```

With digits in cyan - sorry, I don't see how to get the forum to render the color from BBCode or HTML or ... -- suggestions will be appreciated.

Best wishes ... cheers, drl